# Laravel new Command is not working on MAC anymore

Tags: laravel, macos, composer-php

I have tried

1. `composer global require laravel/installer`
2. `nano ~/.bash_profile`
3. `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"`

according to laravel documentation but `laravel new FOLDER` is not working

its saying

```
sharif@Sharifs-MacBook-Pro ~ % laravel new
zsh: command not found: laravel
```

any idea or solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should fix it

1. `nano ~/.zshrc`
2. `export PATH=$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`

Comment: it worked like a charm but also need to execute one more command
`source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: @Sharif I realize you're new to this site so you're probably unaware that typically you should accept the answer containing better detail that was posted 5 hours earlier than the answer you accepted. Your accepted answer just repeated the same information with fewer details.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding the `export` to the `~/.bash_profile` file you'll need to add it to your `~/.zshrc` file because according to the error your `$SHELL` is ZSH and not bash. Apple recently changed the default shell in macOS to ZSH away from bash.

I did this in my `~/.zshrc`: `export PATH=$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`